# Flutter Riverpod - Avoiding passing parameters each time

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod, state-management

I have this `CurrentUser` class which takes in a `uid`. I initialize this provider when my app checks the user's authentication status. I want to be able to `watch` or `read` this provider without having to pass the `uid` every time.

Also, I'm looking for a way so that if I'm not passing the `uid`, the build method doesn't have to fetch the data, and just uses its current state.

Is any of this possible?

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class CurrentUser extends _$CurrentUser {
  @override
  Future<User> build({required String uid}) async {
    return await ref.read(firestoreRepoProvider).getUser(uid: uid);
  }

  //...other methods to mutate state
}
```

Comment: If the uid is app-wide unique, move it to its own provider, then watch that provider in this provider to get the value.  If it's not unique, and must be per-provider, then it's a family key and must be passed to select the appropriate provider instance.

Comment: This isn't the approach I went with (though I believe it would work), but your comment did inspire my solution. My brain must've been on empty, because this seems obvious in hindsight. I ended up having a provider for Firebase's authStateChanges stream, which I can obtain the uid from.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `StateProvider<User?>`, storing the current user. If no user is connected, the value would be `null`.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello ${ref.watch(currentUserProvider)?.name}'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('login'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Fake retrieve user from server, for instance:
                    // final User user = await ref.read(firestoreRepoProvider).getUser(uid: uid);
                    ref.read(currentUserProvider.notifier).state = User('John', 'uid');
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('logout'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Fake logout
                    ref.read(currentUserProvider.notifier).state = null;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final StateProvider<User?> currentUserProvider = StateProvider<User?>((_) => null);

class User {
  User(this.name, this.uid);
  final String name;
  final String uid;
}
```

I created a currentUserProvider, that can be watched within your widgets.
I added 2 buttons to fake login and logout, to show you how to update the current user.